# Send tweets from appengine + python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, twitter

I'm looking to send tweets from a small app I'm building for the appengine, but can't quite understand how the whole oAuth and all that works.

I have seen from some very basic examples in here (which didn't work for me) to more elaborated examples using tweepy. I've also been to tweepy samples, and found some useful stuff in there, but nothing that really got me going for anything.

I think I'm finding too complex examples and am a bit worried about re-inventing the wheel.

I basically have some text that is generated by another application, and I wanna pass this text and tweet it from a twitter account.

Is there any simple way of doing that? In the past I've done it with basic authentication, but I know it's no longer available.

Comment: Twitter has plenty of twits on it already. Editing to tweets.

Comment: Ha... or tweets even ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps see if any of the other [Python Twitter libraries](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#python) are easier to wrap your mind around?

For instance, `python-twitter` has a very simple interface:

```
>>> api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer_key',
    consumer_secret='consumer_secret', access_token_key='access_token',
    access_token_secret='access_token_secret')

>>> api.PostUpdate('I love python-twitter!')
```

Comment: if they only make HTTP calls, yes. They may need monkey-patching to use GAE's HTTP lib. GAE just stops you from using sockets, files, etc. HTTP protocols like twitter API are fine.

Comment: nope... python-twitter doesn't work on google app engine... even this simple example you posted will fail with "NotImplementedError: Only tempfile.TemporaryFile is available for use"

Answer (score 1):

I found this little Twitter-OAuth implementation for python GAE a while back and used it with great success. Mostly as a testing tool for implementing my own OAuth provider though.

Check it out at [tweetapp@github](https://github.com/tav/tweetapp/blob/master/standalone/twitter_oauth_handler.py). He demoes it here: http://twitteroauth.appspot.com.

He does mention that he stopped maintaining that code a while back, but it still works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I too used twitteroauth.appspot.com for OAuth. There's also
[tweetengine](https://github.com/Arachnid/tweetengine) with models for UserAccount, TwitterAccount and GoogleUserAccount.

Comment: I wrote Tweet Engine, so I'm biased, but I think it's a pretty decent example of how to use Twitter OAuth from App Engine.